# Celsius converter on VB running into Strict Option errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm hoping someone can clarify what I'm doing wrong here. I am trying to make a form with 2 labels - Celsius and Fahrenheit with 2 respective textbooks for the Value and 1 button - Convert to display the conversion of Celsius into Fahrenheit. The following Code I use keeps running me into Strict Options errors, 2 for Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'String' and 2 for Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Double'. I can't seem to find a way to please the strict options.

```
 Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim celsius As String
    Dim answer As String
    Dim fahrenheit As String

    celsius = txtCelsius.Text
    fahrenheit = txtFahrenheit.Text

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFahrenheit.Text) Then
        answer = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
        txtFahrenheit.Text = Int(answer)
    End If
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCelsius.Text) Then
        answer = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
        txtCelsius.Text = Int(answer)
```

Comment: Tip: Your celsius, fahrenheit and answer variables should be numeric types, not strings. That will make your errors easier to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Option Strict On**

You need to do conversion yourself

I have edited your code, Try this

```
        Dim celsius As String
        Dim answer As String
        Dim fahrenheit As String

        celsius = txtCelsius.Text
        fahrenheit = txtFahrenheit.Text

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFahrenheit.Text) Then
            answer = CStr(CDbl(celsius) * 9 / 5 + 32)
            txtFahrenheit.Text = answer
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCelsius.Text) Then
            answer = CStr((CDbl(fahrenheit) - 32) * 5 / 9)
            txtCelsius.Text = answer
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many implicit conversions that can be fixed/made explicit:

You have implicit conversion in the `celsius * 9 / 5 + 32`and `(fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9`. 
`celcius` and `farhenheit` are strings, but you're using it as a numbers.

You also have when you put the result into answer:
`answer = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32`
`answer` is a string but you're assigning the result of a calculation. It properly should be a double or similar datatype and not a string.

And then when you put `Int(answer)` into a textfield.
first `answer` is still a string, but `Int()` takes a number (double) if I remember right.  Then you take that result and put automatically into a string:
`txtCelsius.Text = Int(answer)`